# Meaning of "go speeding past"

Tags: meaning, idioms

> Sometimes days **go speeding past**

I know every words of this phase, just don't know the meaning of this combination.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is kind of a bit of personification. You can imagine a car "speeding past" you if it drives very quickly past you on the street.

The language here applies this idea to a day instead of a physical object. It just means that the day seems to go quickly.

On the other hand, a day could 'crawl along', meaning time goes very slowly.

Answer (score 3):

It means time goes quickly: *tempus fugit*.

Comment: Tempus? Fuhgeddaboutit!